# how do I install ruby-glade-create-template ? Which is the gem that provides it?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, glade, ruby-gnome2

I am on Ubuntu with ruby 1.9.1 and i am trying to build a ui with Glade. Glade outputs glade files (xml) which have to be translated to .rb . It's full of examples where "ruby-glade-create-template" is used to do this .

Seems easy except it's 2 days i have been looking for the right gem to provide that script, or for the right deb package, or for the right tarball.

From ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp :

ruby-glade-create-template is a program provided by Ruby/Libglade2.

Ok, and libglade is in ruby-gnome2.

Ruby-GNOME2 1.0.3 released - http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?News_20110918_3

First option: install it as a gem - gem install gtk2

Or get:

ruby-gtk2-1.0.3.tar.gz - The minimum package which includes Ruby/GLib2, Ruby/GIO2, Ruby/ATK, Ruby/GdkPixbuf2, Ruby/Pango, Ruby/GTK2.

or ruby-gnome2-all-1.0.3.tar.gz - All of Ruby-GNOME2 libraries. (this should be the one to include libglade which has ruby-glade-create-template)

So i downloaded last tarball, ran make, and make install but still i can't find ruby-glade-create-template

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time the question was asked *ruby-glade-create-template* was in the libglade2-ruby package. 
It could also be installed as part of the ruby-gnome2: https://github.com/wyhaines/ruby-gnome2/blob/master/libglade/bin/ruby-glade-create-template

About now this solution has long way been abandoned (just giving a decent end to this old question of mine ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Libglade has been deprecated in favor of GtkBuilder: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/devel-announce-list/2009-May/msg00003.html